# How to check if a string is false or empty in dustjs?

Tags: dust.js

Consider these two JSON objects:

```
{
  note: false
}
```

or

`{
   note: ""
 }`

And if the below code is used to check note value, it prints ccccc in both the cases.

`{@select key=note}
    {@eq value=false}aaaa{/eq}
    {@eq value=true}bbbb{/eq}
    {@default}ccccc{/default}
 {/select}`

Can anyone suggest if there is any other way available to get different output in case of **false** and **empty**?

Comment: I notice that you are asking a lot of dust questions recently. Most of your questions can be answered by reading the documentation at http://www.dustjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Cast to strings. Also, if you're using an up-to-date `dust-helpers`, you should use `{@none}` instead of `{@default}`.

```
{@select key=note}
   {@eq value="false" type="string"}note was false{/eq}
   {@eq value=""}note was empty string{/eq}
   {@eq value="true" type="string"}note was true{/eq}
   {@none}note was something else{/none}
{/select}
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry, the question might have been very basic, henceforth I'll go through the documentation.